# Firefox no longer asks me which folder to save new bookmarks to

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

When I bookmark a website in Firefox, either by clicking the star next to the URL bar or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, I used to see a window that prompted me to select a folder to save the bookmark to. I'm not seeing it anymore. What happened? I'm afraid that I'm not going to be able to find my bookmarks anymore.

Comment: Just clicking the star here never brought up any window.

Comment: was really handy. without this funtionality you have to "edit" every time after bookmarking the url and set it into the predefined folder...

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but had you just upgraded to a new version of Firefox when you asked? I seem to remember the default changing from "ask for folder" to "put in unsorted folder" a while back as a result of an upgrade.

Some add-ons have been reported to be responsible, as seen in [this Mozilla support forum thread](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/769435#answer-122636).